# Fixing interfaces

Tags: internet, web-interface

Ok so long story short, my raspberry I is no longer connecting to the Internet. I did some research and found that the interfaces file is not in the interfaces.d folder and I'm trying to move it. The I used not the sudo cp and sudo mv commands and they're not recognizing the destination. I've entered it as just "interfaces.d", "/ect/network/interfaces.d", and about a dozen variations of each. I need help.

Comment: Start again from scratch.  We have no idea what you have done and neither do you.

Comment: the `interfaces` file usually lives in `/etc/network` - see the [man page](http://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/5/interfaces/) - alternatively run `man interfaces` to get the same information as that page

Answer (score 1):

I agree with joan.

The tutorial [How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697) describes the contents and locations of configuration files (assuming you are using a recent Raspbian - which you haven't specified).

There is ABSOLUTELY NO REASON to fiddle with `/etc/network/interfaces`.

If you have done any other damage you may have to start from scratch.